# Angular Material FAB Dial button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've been trying Angular Material and using the FAB Speed Dial, using their demo, I played around but I can't see to have it running properly, I modified the HTML source markup and just left the js side unmodified. Here is what I modded on the source code

```
<md-fab-speed-dial md-open="false" md-direction="down" ng-class="md-fling">
        <md-fab-trigger>
          <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
<some other code...>
```

As you can see, compared to the DEMO source code they wrote, `md-open`, `md-direction` and `ng-class` was modified by me and just change it to the actual value. But the result is this

[image]

It won't hide the buttons neither does that button menu function work. Here is the code pen link from their Demos [FAB Speed Dial Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for `ng-class` you set "down" but in their example there are possible two values:

- 'md-fling'
- 'md-scale'

so it should be for instance:

```
ng-class="'md-fling'"
```

Comment: opps sorry my bad, i have set the value of md-scale or md-fling.. same result

Comment: remember that you must pass it as a string so you need single quotes inside double quotes, exactly as in my example.

Comment: ohhh.. it worked, i find it weird though, isn't is already a string?

Comment: ng-class needs expression in it (not string), so it assumes that what you pass is a variable and it tries to get the value of variable called md-fling (like in Angular Material example - they pass variable without qoutes and it sets its value as a class). But if you want to set "hardcoded" string you can also use class="md-fling" (this time without single qoutes).